# apex clasic report how to click a row and go to another page (kind of master detail)

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

How can I click a row in a classic report and then jump to another page? something like the detail of the row clicked

Answer (score 1):

As Littlefoot said, you can create a link column via the query. Another option is to right-click **Columns** under the region in the Page Designer and select **Create Virtual Column**. Then set the **Type** of the new column to **Link**. Then you can use the declarative **Target** attribute in the Link section to configure your link.

You might want to read the following sections of the doc:

- [Understanding Session State Management](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmdb/understanding-session-state-management.html#GUID-CE2A38B5-75B7-4C43-ACB0-685E16C6ACF9)
- [Understanding URL Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.2/htmdb/understanding-url-syntax.html#GUID-F9B81EAF-D33F-401D-8349-3952DEDA5460)

The basic idea is that you will navigate to the form page and set the value of a primary key item (or GUID) via URL syntax. Then the form page will pick up on the value and use it to fetch the row and render the page.

Answer (score 0):

You'd create a **link column**.

Something like this:

```
with test as
  (select level page_number 
   from dual 
   connect by level <= 3
  )
select 
  t.page_number,
  '<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:' || t.page_number ||':&APP_SESSION.' || '">Click here </a>' link
from test t
```

I don't know what you're doing, but - in this example - the `test` CTE returns numbers 1, 2, 3 (as rows) and uses them as link target page, i.e. those links lead you to pages 1, 2, 3 in the same application.

I presume you have something *smarter* than this, but - the principle remains the same.

In `link` column's properties you'd just set "Escape special characters" property to "No".